# Micrometer With Microservice

Tags: spring-boot, influxdb, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am newbie to micrometer. could anyone let me know how to manage microservice metrics centrally in spring boot ?

Where i can get all registered service information and matrices and stored metrics in influxdb ?

Comment: Have you read the docs: https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/16/micrometer-spring-boot-2-s-new-application-metrics-collector https://www.baeldung.com/micrometer

Comment: Yeah. I went through this tutorial but its good for monolithic application. I am looking for microservice where i can write code centrally for allmicroservice

Comment: What do you mean by "write code centrally"?

Comment: Centrally in the sense of i do not have to write code in each microservice for monitoring. I am not sure is this possible ?

Comment: If you are using Acutator there are some default metrics. But if you want to measure anything service specific you have to implement that case by case.

Comment: Oh, Tha means if i have to monitor particular service than i have to write configuration for each microservice right ?

Comment: That depends on what you want to measure. What are your requriements

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're asking "How to use Micrometer with Spring Boot for collecting metrics from heterogeneous services which have multiple instances on multiple hosts" as there is nothing special with the microservice architecture compared to the assumed environment, you need to add dimensions to metrics for hosts, application instances, and so on. You can achieve it with the common tags support. See [the section for it in the Spring Boot reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-common-tags).

UPDATED:

To answer the additional question on the below comment, I created [a sample showing how to use common tags with environment variables](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/common-tags-2.1.x-with-env). Note that it's on the branch `common-tags-2.1.x-with-env`, not the `master`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Sound good but where i can keep common tag ? lets say i have docker image for microservice-1 and i have coded for "region-1". This region name added to my yml file.  now i have hosted microservice-1 in region-2 in this case ii has sill same yml file so it tagged again region -1..  much confusion for me.

Comment: @BhargavPatel You can use environment variables like other properties in Spring Boot. I updated the answer to have a link to a sample demonstrating it.

Comment: @BhargavPatel, all your instances for the same service has the same environment.  How can you  have a unique tag per instance?  Also how would you aggregate the data across instances?

Comment: @AlwynSchoeman You can pass ENV variable which can by-forget unique instance on start up of your service